# How to control one Word document from another Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to use a master file, referred to as mDoc to copy charts from a slave file, called sDoc. It seems the code works during the first loop, but on the second and all subsequent loops, no charts are copied from the master to the slave.

```vb
Sub CopyAllCharts()
    
    Dim objShape As InlineShape
    Dim mDoc As Document
    Dim sDoc As Document
    
    Path = "C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\word_docs\"
    File = Dir(Path & ".")
    
    Do While File <> ""
    
        Set mDoc = Documents("Testing.docm")
        Set sDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=Path & File)
    
        Windows(sDoc).Activate
        Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name
        
        For Each objShape In sDoc.InlineShapes
            Debug.Print objShape.HasChart
            If objShape.HasChart Then
                objShape.Chart.Select
                Selection.Copy
    
                Windows(mDoc).Activate
                Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name
                
                Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
                Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            End If
        Next objShape
    
    sDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    File = Dir()
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

During the first loop, these lines select and print the active document's name.

```
Windows(mDoc).Activate
Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name
```

On the second and all other loops, `Windows(mDoc).Activate` does NOT activate the master document and `Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name` prints the slave document's name but not the master document's name.

Comment: It is best not to rely on which document is active. Instead, save the word objects you are using in variables, and then use those instead.

Comment: Stop using the Selection object. The Selection object is slow and inherently unreliable. Use _Range_ instead. Then you don't have to activate a document. Then use Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd, otherwise you're at risk for over-writing the chart you pasted previously.

Comment: Can you post some sample code? I Googled it, and found the link below, which looked promising, but I still can't get this thing to work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-range-objects

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/84645-post2.html, http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?51139-Copy-text-from-old-table-to-new-table&p=317369&viewfull=1#post317369

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the Range thing working, and made some progress, but in the end, I couldn't quite get it to work the way I wanted. Ultimately, I went with the code sample below, which does what I want.

```
Sub CopyAllCharts()

Dim objShape As InlineShape
Dim mDoc As Document
Dim sDoc As Document

Path = "C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\word_docs\"
File = Dir(Path & ".")

Do While File <> ""

Set mDoc = Documents("Control One Word Document From Another Word Document.docm")
Set sDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=Path & File)


    Windows(sDoc).Activate
    If sDoc.Name = ActiveDocument.Name Then
        Windows(sDoc).Activate
        Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name
        
        For Each objShape In sDoc.InlineShapes
            Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name
            Debug.Print objShape.HasChart
            
            If objShape.HasChart Then
                objShape.Chart.Select
                Selection.Copy
                    If mDoc.Name <> ActiveDocument.Name Then
                        Windows(mDoc).Activate
                    End If
                Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name
                Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
                Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            End If
        
        Windows(sDoc).Activate
        Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name
        Next objShape
    End If
sDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
File = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```